# Pytest fixtures importing

Tags: python, pytest

So let's say I have this scenario:

```py
tests:
    fixtures:
        fix1.py
        fix2.py
        fix3.py
```

Where there are dependencies between fixtures `fix1->fix2->fix3` i.e. `fix1.py` is defining a fixture that is using a fixture defined in `fix2.py` etc.

So when I want to use fixture `f1` from `fix1.py` in `some_test.py` I do it like:

```py
from tests.fixtures.fix1 import f1
```

But pytest requires me to import all dependencies from `fix2` then also from `fix3` so import statements in `some_test.py` are expanding.
Even this scenario requires additional imports in `some_test.py`:

```
# `fix1.py` src
def fA():
    pass

def fB(fA):
    pass


# `some_test.py` src
from tests.fixtures.fix1 import fA, fB # Instead of just importing fB
```

Seems kinda redundant to me, anyone has any idea why is this the case?

Comment: does your fix1.py import fix2.py?

Comment: The usual pytest  way is to put all fixtures into `conftest.py` (on different levels, if needed), so that they will be found automatically by pytest - no need to import them in the tests.

Comment: + for conftest.py, there is also a great doc on fixture discovery: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/fixtures.html#fixture-availability